# Is this a bug in GCC?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, name-lookup

EDIT: This is not a bug, just me not knowing about [dependent name lookups in templated base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643074/21475) (which MSVC "helpfully" resolves without errors).

---

I wrote a functor implementation a while back, and a simple "Event" wrapper that uses it. It compiles fine under MSVC, but GCC gives an error about a member variable in the base class, `subscribers`, not being declared; changing `subscribers` to `this->subscribers` resolves the issue(!). It appears to happen only with the curiously recurring template pattern, and with partial template specialization.

Simplified source (sorry for the mind-bending template usage...):

```
#include <vector>

template<typename TEvent>
struct EventBase
{
protected:
        std::vector<int> subscribers;
};

template<typename TArg1 = void, typename TArg2 = void>
struct Event : public EventBase<Event<TArg1, TArg2> >
{
        void trigger(TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2) const
        {
                // Error on next line
                auto it = subscribers.cbegin();
        }
};

template<typename TArg1>
struct Event<TArg1, void> : public EventBase<Event<TArg1> >
{
        void trigger(TArg1 arg1) const
        {
                // Using `this` fixes error(?!)
                auto it = this->subscribers.cbegin();
        }
};

template<>
struct Event<void, void> : public EventBase<Event<> >
{
        void trigger() const
        {
                // No error here even without `this`, for some reason!
                auto it = subscribers.cbegin();
        }
};

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Am I invoking undefined behaviour somewhere? Is my syntax somehow wrong? Is this really a bug in GCC? Is it perhaps a known bug? Any insight would be appreciated!

More details: Compiled using `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`. I'm using GCC version 4.7.2. Exact error message:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Event<TArg1, TArg2>::trigger(TArg1, TArg2) const’:
main.cpp:17:15: error: ‘subscribers’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: I've ran into this too. As a rule of thumb, if it involves templates, always trust gcc over msvc (I find that gcc is right 99.9 percent of the time).

Comment: @JesseGood There is even a duplicate [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11405/819272) from yet another MSVC refugee. Apparently, gcc fixed it somewhere in the 3.4 release, breaking some old code in the process. But hey, who said vendors need bug-compatibility as a selling point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is a bug in MSVC instead**. Names from dependent base classes have to be "thisambiguated".

The reason is that unqualified lookup of dependent names [**proceeds in two phases**](http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html). During the first phase, the base class is not yet known and the compiler cannot resolve the name. MSVC does not implement two-phase name lookup and delays the lookup until the second phase.

The full specialization

```
template<>
struct Event<void, void> : public EventBase<Event<> >
{
        void trigger() const
        {
                // No error here even without `this`, for some reason!
                auto it = subscribers.cbegin();
        }
};
```

does not suffer from this problem, because both the class and its base are regular classes, not class templates, and there is no template dependency to begin with.

When porting C++ code from MSVC to gcc/Clang, dependent name lookup disambiguation and the [`template` keyword disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/819272) (i.e. calling member function template using `::template`, `->template` or `.template` syntax) are two of the subtleties that you have to deal with ([empty base optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12701469/819272) is another one). For all the Standards compliance rhetoric, this will probably never be fixed for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Could you explain further? Why isn't it an error in the last case? (Nice pun btw.)

Comment: @Cameron:  The last case is not a template, it's a full specialization.  Everything about it is known at compile-time.

Comment: @Cameron The C++ FAQ has an [explanation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html) of why `this->` is required in that case. It works on MSVC because it doesn't implement two-phase name lookup for templates.

Comment: Aha, thanks all. Silly me for jumping to conclusions about compiler bugs. Yet another corner of C++ that I never knew existed :-)

Comment: @Cameron I've been bitten by this too!