# Using SIMD in a Game Engine Math Library by using function pointers ~ A good idea?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, game-engine, simd

I have been reading Game Engine Books since I was 14 (At that time I didn't understand a thing:P)
Now quite some years later I wanted to start programming the Mathmatical Basis for my Game Engine. I've been thinking long about how to design this 'library'. (Which I mean as "Organized set of files") Every few years new SIMD instructionsets come out, and I wouldn't want them to go to waste. (Tell me if I am wrong about this.)

I wanted to at least have the following properties:

- Making it able to check if it has SIMD at runtime, and use SIMD if it has it and uses the normal C++ version if it doesn't. (Might have some call overhead, is this worth it?)
- Making it able to compile for SIMD or normal C++ if we already know the target at compile time. The calls can get inlined and made suitable for Cross-Optimisation because the compiler knows if SIMD or C++ is used.

**EDIT - I want to make the sourcecode portable so it can run on other deviced then x86(-64) too**

So I thought it would be a good solution to use function pointers which I would make static and initialize at the start of the program. And which the suited functions(For example multiplication of Matrix/Vector) will call.

What do you think are the advantages and disadvantages(Which outweights more?) of this design and is it even possible to create it with both properties as described above?

Christian

Comment: You might want to look at [compiler intrinsic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) functions. There are many that maps directly to SIMD instructions, and if the target platform doesn't support that specific instruction the compilers today should be smart enough to emulate the instruction. See g.e. [here for VS2012 intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: SSE2 instructions have been available for at least 10 years now. Are you sure you care about games running on older machines (assuming we're not talking games on mobile phones or something like that).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I edited my question! I forgot the very important goal to add that it must be portable to about any system.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think it's nice that they emulate it, but I wouldn't want my code to be compiler specific which it will be if I use compiler intrinsics from VS2012.

Comment: You will have some "unportable" code if you are using SIMD extensions. The intrinsics are actually fairly portable, as they work with VS, GCC and Intel compilers. Obviously, not on ARM or PowerPC processors...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I understand that. I want it to be able to decide at runtime and compiletime(for inlining) if they are supported, so it's possible to use it on ARM or PowerPC.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to get the right granularity at which you make decision on which routine to call. If you do this at too low a level then function dispatch overhead becomes a problem, e.g. a small routine which just has a few instructions could become very inefficient if called via some kind of function pointer dispatch mechanism rather than say just being inlined. Ideally the architecture-specific routines should be processing a reasonable amount of data so that function dispatch cost is negligible, without being so large that you get significant code bloat due to compiling additional non-architecture-specific code for each supported architecture.

Comment: Since most functions in a math library are rather small, would you suggest dropping the property of it being able to deduce if it has SIMD at runtime and use it if available? and moving the decision of using SIMD to a higher level? I am sure it would be more efficiënt but it's probably unavoidable to get code bloat that way.

Comment: Typically to get any real benefit from SIMD each routine should operate on a reasonably large data set, i.e. not just say adding two SIMD vectors, but adding two 1D or 2D arrays. That way you get good efficiency with the routine itself and the function dispatch overhead is not significant. Look at how Intel handles this in e.g. its IPP library.

Comment: I can find the IPP library on Intels site, but do you mayby have a link to the insides of the library? How would you suggest me to design my math library?

Comment: If you read the online documentation for IPP it talks about the dispatch mechanism. As for design, that's a big subject, but essentially what I said above: design your library functions so that they operate on a sufficiently large data set, e.g. a row, tile or block of pixels in the case of image processing. Ideally you should process chunks of data that fit within cache so that you can combine multiple function calls on the same data while it's still in cache.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to compile your game twice, once with SIMD enabled, once without. Create a tiny little launcher app that performs the _may_i_use_cpu_feature checks, and then runs the correct build.

The double indirection caused by calling a matrix multiply (for example) via a function pointer is not going to be nice. Instead of inlining trivial maths functions, it'll introduce function calls all over the shop, and those calls will be forced to save/restore a lot of registers to boot (because the code behind the pointer is not going to be know until runtime).

At that point, a non-optimised version without the double indirection will massively outperform the SSE version with function pointers.

As for supporting multiple platforms, this can be easy, and it can also be a real bother. ARM neon is similar enough to SSE4 to make it worth wrapping the intructions behind some macros, however neon is also different enough to be really annoying!

```
#if CPU_IS_INTEL

#include <immintrin.h>
typedef __m128 f128;

#define add4f _mm_add_ps

#else

#include <neon.h>
typedef float32x4 f128;

#define add4f vqadd_f32

#endif
```

The MAJOR problem with starting on say Intel, and porting to ARM later is that a lot of the nice things don't exist. Shuffling is possible on ARM, but it's also a bother. Division, dot product, and sqrt don't exist on ARM (only reciprocal estimates, which you'll need to do your own newton iteration on)

If you are thinking about SIMD like this:

```
struct Vec4 
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  float w;
};
```

Then you *may* just be able to wrap SSE and NEON behind a semi-ok wrapper. When it comes to AVX512 and AVX2 though, you'll probably be screwed.

If however you are thinking about SIMD using structure-of-array formats:

```
struct Vec4SOA
{
  float x[BIG_NUM];
  float y[BIG_NUM];
  float z[BIG_NUM];
  float w[BIG_NUM];
};
```

Then there is a chance you'll be able to produce an AVX2/AVX512 version. However, working with code organised like that is not the easiest thing in the world.