# sorting a string vector based on the string size

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I wanted to know how I can sort a string vector such that the string with the least amount of characters is on top of the vector. For instance if the vector has ABCD,ABCDE,ABC in it. ABC gets to the top.I would be interested to know how this could be achieved with sort_if and what the predicate would look like ? Any other methods are also welcome

Comment: The is no `std::sort_if()`. There is an overload of `std::sort()` taking predicate, though. The predicate would, obviously, compare the length of arguments and if they are equal compare the lexicographical order of the strings; otherwise it would return `true` if the first argument is shorter.

Comment: FYI - these answers are now very outdated, no need for an overloaded operator now, simply use a lambda!

Comment: Example for sorting using lambda expression: `std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), [](std::string a, std::string b) {return a.length() < b.length(); });`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make your own custom functor to compare the size of string(s) and use that to sort the strings.

```
struct compare {
    inline bool operator()(const std::string& first,
            const std::string& second) const
    {
        return first.size() < second.size();
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> v;
compare c;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), c);
```

In modern c++ we can use a lambda to do the same

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), []
    (const std::string& first, const std::string& second){
        return first.size() < second.size();
    });
```

Comment: You probably want to order the strings lexicographically if they are of the same length. The function call operator should probably be `const`.

Comment: You don't need to make a functor to do this.  A simple comparison function will do it as well.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'd think you just want to be stable if they are the same length. Guess that's up to the asker.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Although semantically this is true, in practice the function object can be inlined while using the function pointer as predicate it often cannot be inlined.

Comment: That is no longer true (and hasn't been for a while actually):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860762/c-can-compilers-inline-a-function-pointer

Answer (score 7):

Should be able to use regular `std::sort(first, last, compare)`, and a compare function like this:

```
bool compareLen(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    return (a.size() < b.size()); 
}
```

Comment: This compareLen is not working for me. I have used your function and invoked it by the line
sort(words.begin(), words.end(), compareLen);

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort` takes an optional argument for a custom comparison

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

You can just define a function that compares based on the length.