# Pass a function as an explicit template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

In the code example below, the call to `foo` works, while the call to `bar` fails.

If I comment out the call to `bar`, the code compiles, which tells me the definition of `bar` itself is fine. So how would `bar` be called correctly?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

template <class F>
void foo(int x, int y, F f)
{
    cout << f(x, y) << endl;
}

template <class F>
void bar(int x, int y)
{
    cout << F(x, y) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(3, 4, multiply); // works
    bar<multiply>(3, 4); // fails

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also see [Function passed as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1174169/608639).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem here is, `multiply` is not a *type*; it is a *value* but the function template `bar` expects the template argument to be a *type*. Hence the error.

If you define the function template as:

```
template <int (*F)(int,int)> //now it'll accept multiply (i.e value)
void bar(int x, int y)
{
    cout << F(x, y) << endl;
}
```

then it will work. See online demo : http://ideone.com/qJrAe

You can simplify the syntax using `typedef` as:

```
typedef int (*Fun)(int,int);

template <Fun F> //now it'll accept multiply (i.e value)
void bar(int x, int y)
{
    cout << F(x, y) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`multiply` is not a type, it's a function. In that context, it decays to a function pointer. However, `bar` is templated for a type which, again, `multiply` is not.

Nawaz already answered the question the other way around (how to change the definition of `bar` to be used with functions), but to answer your explicit question of how to call `bar` as you have it, you need a suitable type, like this:

```
struct Type {
  const int result;
  Type(int x, int y): result(x * y) {}
  operator int() const { return result; }
};

// usage
bar<Type>(x, y);

// (edit) a suitable type doesn't necessarily mean a new type; this works as well
// if you aren't trying to solve any specific problem
bar<std::string>(64, 64);
```

Comment: If he is going to use this, then he needs to change `bar` as well. The syntax `F(x,y)` should become `F(x,y)()`.

Comment: @Nawaz No, `Type` isn't actually a functor. It's just a type with a suitable constructor and a stream output overload (in this case a suitable conversion operator that already has a stream output overload). (see http://ideone.com/AgQGc)

Comment: Ohh.. I overlooked that... possibly because a functor would be a better alternative here, therefore I was expecting that.