# Passing C++ functions as arguments without function pointer/inlined?

Tags: c++, function, templates

What is the correct way to pass functions (with the same input arguments/return type) as arguments to another function, without function pointers being used? I would like the function argument passed in to be inlined when it is called? Well, I just don't want the pointer indirection.

I found this:

[Pass a function as an explicit template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871100/pass-a-function-as-an-explicit-template-parameter)

but it seems to be using function pointers.

EDIT: I'd really really really like to avoid having to create structs to store the behaviour for each function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specialization at compilation time, you just need to pass type information:

```
void inlined_function() {}; // function you want to pass

template<typename F> void caller1() {
    inlined_function(); // not passed through pointer, call inline
}
```

If you have control of the inline function, implement it as a functor:

```
struct X {
    inline void operator()() // inline function
    {
    }
};

template<typename F> void caller2(F functor) {
    functor(); // inline call
}
```

Client code for the two variants:

```
caller1<inlined_function>();
caller2(X{});
```

**Edit**:

If you do not have control to write the functor as a structure, write an inline structure wrapper for it.

E.g., you have `void inlined_function() {};` and need to write `caller2`. In this case, write a functor similar to `X` that calls `inlined_function`, or (better yet), a lambda:

```
template<typename F> void caller2(F functor) {
    functor(); // inline call
}

caller2( [](){ inlined_functor(); } );
```

Comment: Hey, I am liking your EDIT idea. So inlined_functor() could also have inlined_functor2() and these would still be normal methods in the same class?

Comment: @user997112 - yes. Inlined functions calling each other results in an inline operation.