# How to set the template parameter to allow flexibility in choosing different kinds of functions

Tags: c++, templates

For example

```
template<class D, Function>
struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        D d;
        int i = Function(d);
        // Here function can be a free function: int fun(D& d)
        // or member function: int D::fun()
        // or function object:
    }
};
```

How to set the template parameter to allow flexibility in choosing different kinds of functions? Code can be changed just allow the flexibility is fine. Thanks

Comment: Is the question is about a [function passed as template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to pass the function around into the class. If you don't pass some object around, you *have* to for example defaut construct such an object to call with:

```
template<class D, typename Function>
struct A
{
    explicit A(Function f) : func_(f) { }

    void foo()
    {
        D d;
        int i = func_(d);
        // Here function can be a free function: int fun(D& d)
        // or member function: int D::fun()
        // or function object:
    }

    Function func_;
};
```

Since callable types are almost always stateless or have tiny internal state there shouldn't be any implications for copying these.

Comment: @user1899020 Very unlikely to matter. Function will be copied into the class, but functors are usually small.