# cuda device function and templates

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I am using CUDA 7 and am trying to pass a function as a template parameter to a device function as follows:

```
typedef float(*Op)(float, float);

template<typename Op>
__device__ bool is_maxima(float ax, float ay, cudaTextureObject_t current)
{
    // I try to use the passed function as:
    float cv = tex2D<float>(current, ax, ay);    
    float pv = tex2D<float>(current, ax - 1.f, ay);
    if (Op(cv, pv) != cv) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Now from my `global` cuda kernel, I call this as follows:

```
__global__ void detect_keypoints(cudaTextureObject_t current
                                 float *result, int width, int height)
{
    const int x = __mul24(blockDim.x, blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x;
    const int y = __mul24(blockDim.y, blockIdx.y) + threadIdx.y;

    float c = tex2D<float>(current, ax + 0.5f, ay + 0.5f);
    float ax = x + 1; float av = y + 1;

    if (is_maxima<fmaxf>(ax + 0.5f, ay + 0.5f, current))
        result[y * width + height] = 1.f;
}
```

However, it gives me a compiler error saying:

```
error: no instance of function template "is_maxima" matches the argument 
list
        argument types are: (float, float, cudaTextureObject_t)
```

Is passing of functions as template parameters not allowed in CUDA device functions? I was under the impression that CUDA now supports all of C++ features.

For completeness, `fmaxf` is defined in the CUDA SDK as:

```
inline float fmaxf(float a, float b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: here we go again, lacking an MCVE.  You've got something that *already* reproduces the error.  Why not provide a complete code?  If you think it's because you're asking a "conceptual" question, you're mistaken, because every debugging question can be mapped into a conceptual question for the purposes of avoiding the MCVE requirement.

Comment: the error message seems to be complaining about the argument list.  Is `current` a valid cuda texture object type?  Also, your template parameter is Op with a capital O, and your code is using op with a small o.  Doesn't look right.

Comment: The small 'o' was a type from me. I corrected it. The texture is valid. I am getting the error at the compilation stage anyway.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The signature should have been: template<typename Op op>
__device__ bool is_maxima(float ax, float ay, cudaTextureObject_t current) and the usage if (op(cv, pv) != cv) return false;

Comment: According to my testing it should be `template<Op op>` not `template<typename Op op>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already pointed out, this is not correct:

```
template<typename Op>
```

I believe it should be:

```
template<Op op>
```

The following code seems to work correctly for me (removing the texturing since it's extraneous to the issue):

```
$ cat t755.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef float(*Op)(float, float);


__device__ float mymax(float a, float b){

  return (a>b)?a:b;
}

template <Op op>
__device__ float test(float d1, float d2){
  return op(d1, d2);
}

__global__ void kernel(){

  float a1 = 1.0f;
  float a2 = 2.0f;
  printf("%f\n", test<mymax>(a1, a2));
}

int main(){

  kernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -std=c++11 t755.cu -o t755
$ ./t755
2.000000
$
```

Comment: yeah, thanks. I figured that out as well after many trial and error.

Comment: also helpful to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879789/thrust-transform-throws-error-bulk-kernel-by-value-an-illegal-memory-access-w

Answer (score 1):

You could define `is_maxima` like this in order to avoid the `typedef`:

```
template<typename Op>
__device__ bool is_maxima(float ax, float ay, cudaTextureObject_t current, Op fun)
{
    float cv = tex2D<float>(current, ax, ay);    
    float pv = tex2D<float>(current, ax - 1.f, ay);
    if (fun(cv, pv) != cv) return false;
    return true;
}
```

And then call it using `is_maxima(ax + 0.5f, ay + 0.5f, current, fmaxf)`.

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1174193/678093