# Why doesn't std::is_invocable accept a non type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, non-type

I recently stumbled upon [std::is_invocable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) that is going to be introduced into the C++17 standard and I am wondering why it needs a user to provide a type for a function pointer as opposed to just providing the function pointer itself which might be more convenient, especially since non type template parameters can now be unconstrained.

What I mean can be explained in the example below

```
void hello_world() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
int main() {
    cout << std::is_invocable_v<decltype(hello_world)> << endl;
    // as opposed to being able to do
    // cout << std::is_invocable_v<hello_world> << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because passing a function pointer as a template parameter will result in a chicken vs egg problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument (don't feel this one is actually a dupe). You'll have to define the type of the function as the first template parameter, but you need the remaining template parameters to do that.

Comment: One is a type, the other is a value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Dude, what are you talking about? C++17, `template auto`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am wondering why it needs a user to provide a type for a function pointer as opposed to just providing the function pointer itself which might be more convenient

Because you *always* have the *type* of the callable that you want to test, but you don't always have the *value* of it as a constant expression. Sure, when you do have the value you have to write out `decltype(foo)` instead of just `foo`, but that seems like a fairly minor burden, and would cover a fairly percentage of the use-case. Not sure it'd be worth the added complexity of having a `template <auto F, class... Args> is_invocable` just so that, sometimes, you as the user don't have to write `decltype`.

Answer (score 4):

The primary use for `std::is_invocable` is to use with types and template parameters. Not to be only usable by directly using function pointers.

Let's change your code a bit and add a useful case:

```
void callF(F function, Args&& args) {
    std::invoke(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Later, in your main

callF(hello_world);
```

You'd like to filter your function to not be callable when the invoke call would be invalid. You can use `std::is_invokable` just like that:

```
auto callF(F function, Args&& args) -> std::enable_if<std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>> {
    std::invoke(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

As you can see, *the types sent as arguments to `std::is_invocable` reflect the arguments sent to `std::invoke`*.

As a bonus, much more than function pointers are supported. Function objects too, and even member function pointers are supported. Right now, you could use the `callF` function like that:

```
callF([](int i){ /* ... */ }, 8);

struct Test { void test() {} };

Test t;

callF(&Test::test, t);
```