# Simplify template function by passing a template as argument possible?

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a smal example illustrating the problem. `solve_bs1_y` and `solve_bs2_y` are implemented completely similar. The only difference is the function call: `solve_bs*_z`. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to pass a template as argument to replace the function call of `solve_bs*_z`. Consequently, I have to implement for each `solve_bs*_z` another `solve_bs*_y`. Is there a way to simplify the code so that I need just one implementation of `solve_bs_y`?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <int x, int y, int offs, class T>
float solve_bs1_z(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  return 1; // to keep it simple
}

template <int x, int y, int offs, class T>
float solve_bs2_z(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  return 2; // to keep it simple
}

// essentially the same as solve_bs2_y
template <int x, int offs, class T>
float solve_bs1_y(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  const float bs_s = 2;

  return    ( solve_bs1_z<x, 0, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + solve_bs1_z<x, 1, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + solve_bs1_z<x, 2, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU))
      * bs_s;
}
// essentially the same as solve_bs1_y
template <int x, int offs, class T>
float solve_bs2_y(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  const float bs_s = 2;

  return    ( solve_bs2_z<x, 0, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + solve_bs2_z<x, 1, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + solve_bs2_z<x, 2, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU) )
      * bs_s;
}

// these are called in the program ..
template<int offs, class T>
float solve_ffd_bs1(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  return    solve_bs1_y<0, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU) +
      solve_bs1_y<1, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU) +
      solve_bs1_y<2, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU);
}

template<int offs, class T>
float solve_ffd_bs2(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  return    solve_bs2_y<0, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU) +
      solve_bs2_y<1, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU) +
      solve_bs2_y<2, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU);
}


int main()
{
    int mat[3][3][3] = {
        {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}},
        {{11,2,3}, {14,5,6}, {17,8,9}},
        {{21,2,3}, {24,5,6}, {27,8,9}}
        };


  solve_ffd_bs2<0>(mat, 1,2,3);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you looking for function pointers as template arguments? see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument

Comment: _The only difference is the function call_. This means that they have the same body? It doesn't make much sense indeed.

Comment: I cannot use function pointers because I use a template in the function I want to simplify. The template is resolved at place.

Comment: @dgrat can you wrap stand-alone functions into static member functions?

Comment: hm ok I didnt see that these are templates, but then why dont you turn `solve_bs1_z<x, 1, offs>` and `solve_bs2_z<x, 1, offs>` into `solve_bs_z<x, 1, offs,1>` and `solve_bs_z<x, 1, offs,2>` ?

Comment: @W.F.
Then I still would need to resolve the type of the template struct :(

Comment: @dgrat No, because you can pass a template template parameter (which you cannot use with function).

Comment: @dgrat not necessarily the struct can by itself be a non-template and serve as name to be passed to your related callee function

Comment: Can you make an example whichs works in cpp.sh as me?

Comment: @dgrat http://cpp.sh/5esvd

Comment: FYI: The code in the OP isn't exactly minimal. I think it hides what you're really trying to do. I made what I think is a better minimal case [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YYor0uXQIAj9uVLO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper version without struct templates:

```
struct s1 {
    template <int x, int y, int offs, class T>
    static float solve_bs_z(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
      return 1; // to keep it simple
    }
};

struct s2 {
    template <int x, int y, int offs, class T>
    static float solve_bs_z(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
      return 2; // to keep it simple
    }
};

template <class Wrapper, int x, int offs, class T>
float solve_bs_y(T mat, float fS, float fT, float fU) {
  const float bs_s = 2;

  return    ( Wrapper::template solve_bs_z<x, 0, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + Wrapper::template solve_bs_z<x, 1, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU)
      + Wrapper::template solve_bs_z<x, 2, offs>(mat, fS, fT, fU))
      * bs_s;
}
```

and then call:

```
solve_bs_y<s1, 0, 1>(...);
```

Comment: This solution is nice, I forgot about using structs.. But it is weird, that we need them. Why is the language not directly supporting struct-less approaches?

Comment: @dgrat *"Why is the language not directly supporting struct-less approaches?"* It might have something to do with the fact that structs cannot be overloaded while functions (even those templated) can. Now when you will pass the name of overloaded templated function as sth like a template template parameter compiler might not be sure which overload is on your mind.

Comment: @dgrat oh I forgot to add that I don't feel a language lawyer so I might be wrong :) When appropriately asked it could be a good question though!

Comment: The language cannot directly support struct-less approaches because the language does not support partial template specialization for a function. AFAIK the reason it does this is because of function overloading (and function template overloading) Herb Sutter [has a good article on this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)