# is there anyway pass function as template parameter?

Tags: c++

i have been working on a project and i need to know that is there anyway passing a function to template class? lets say i want this to perform sinus or cosinus function

```
#ifndef INTEGRAL_H
#define INTEGRAL_H

template<class F>
class Integral
{
    public:
        Integral( F func):f_(func){}
        ~Integral()=default;
         Integral(){
            int a,b,N;
            double h=(b-a)/N;
            sum=0.0;
            for (size_t j=0; j<N;++j)
                {
                sum+=f_(a+j*h); // here i would like to perform sin(a+j*h) or cosinus or somethingelse
                }

            sum*=h;

        }

        double Sum(){return sum;}

    private:
        F f_;
        double sum;

};

#endif // INTEGRAL_H
```

Comment: I would recommend that you pass a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object instead. No templates needed.

Comment: Your code should work totally fine as-is. Can you elaborate what the problem is?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what the question is and how the posted code relates to it.#

Comment: @MaxLanghof, the problem might be that `std::sin` is not a function, but a template.

Comment: @Evg Then that would be good to have in the question (preferably from the start, seeing as it would invalidate the current answer).

Comment: Yes, there's no point posting a vague goal and some code and no context on how they relate and why the code doesn't work.

Comment: it gives error  when i initialize as   Integral<sin()>  myintegral; or any other type(ddouble,int as template parameter)  but i may use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function here if nothing happens i will ask again, thanks so much

Comment: do you really need to store the function as member? I would rather make the function type not part of the type of the `Integral` but rather let it accept any callable to be integrated

Comment: @LokmanTasbas "it gives error" is not a problem description. What error? For what line? [Edit] your post to quote it in full.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, the whole class looks superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works "as coded" (after a small fix in the constructor, unrelated to the question). But [`std::sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) doesn't name a single function, and you can't pass it into `Integral` directly. The simplest way is to wrap it into a lambda:

```
Integral i([](auto arg) { return std::sin(arg); });
double value = i.Sum();
```

If your compiler doesn't support [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) (available since C++17), you have to be more verbose:

```
auto my_sin = [](auto arg) { return std::sin(arg); };
Integral<decltype(my_sin)> i(my_sin);
double value = i.Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help: [Function passed as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)

In the end, a function is nothing but an address to a particular place in memory which boils down to a simple number and that is something that the template system supports.

However, in your case I would recommend just passing an `std::function` object which is a glorified function pointer as a regular parameter to your function - omitting the need for a template (at least for this part of the functionality).

Comment: ...unless it is overloaded, or itself a template (for not-yet-known arguments).

Comment: what you wrote does not apply for `std::sin` or `std::cos`. As Max said, you cannot get the adress of an overload set

Answer (score 1):

> is there anyway pass function as template parameter?

Yes. Example:

```
template<return_type (template_argument_name)(argument_list)>
```

Another approach is to pass a callable type as template parameter, and invoke an object of that type. This is in fact what you've done in your example.