# How do I force the compiler to evaluate a switch at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm working on an embedded project (only C++14 compiler available) and I would like to optimize the speed of execution.

Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
enum gpio_type{
  TYPE_1,
  TYPE_2
}

template <gpio_type T>
class test{
  test(){}

  void set_gpio(bool output)
  {
    switch (T)
    {
      case TYPE_1:
        do_something();
        break;

      case TYPE_2:
        do_something_else();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Will the compiler automatically remove the dead code at compile time? If it does, it is a standard feature or compiler dependent? If it does not, is it possible to write the code in a way that will force optimizing?

Comment: why not specialize `set_gpio` for the different enum values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant propagation and dead code elimination are one of the simplest compiler optimizations. And since `T` is a compile time constant I would be extremely extremely surprised if the code isn't optimized by any compiler.

I have [tested 15 compilers and platforms on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rb5Zkp) from the venerable x86 to arm, avr, risc-v, raspberry and arduino (and more). All of them just compile to the equivalent of a tail call jump. No tests, no conditional jumps. Go check it out for yourself.

At this point I can say with reasonable confidence that there is no performance reason to modify your code.

Comment: Nice, this is a very good way of testing all kind of code optimization! thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could specialize `set_gpio` for the different enum values - eg. :

```
template <gpio_type T>
class test{
  public:
    test(){}

    void set_gpio(bool output);
};

template<> void test<TYPE_1>::set_gpio(bool output) {
  do_something();
}

template<> void test<TYPE_2>::set_gpio(bool output) {
  do_something_else();
}
```

As other answers have indicated, you might not need to if your compiler is anywhere close to decent at optimizing. But the above might be more readable nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

That might depend on if you turn on optimization or not and how intelligent your compiler is. I guess current compilers would optimize in this case at least if they inline the function.

But if you want to be 100% sure

- specialize the template for different enum values or
- use your switch and look at the assembler output of your compiler to check if the compiler optimized like you want it or
- use C++17 and `if constexpr`

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the functor (`do_something` or `do_something_else`) as a template argument.

Thus, your code of `set_gpio` becomes clearer and you are sure to have a compile time deduction which function to take.

In this post you can see how this is done:
[Function passed as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)