# How to generically convert a string to another type using a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class containing a string member variable and am trying to write a template function that will allow me to convert the string to another type. As a simplified example, without templates this is what I would do.

```cpp
struct A {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
};

void Test(const A& a) {
    // Get the final token value as an int, or default to 42.
    int i = a.tokens.empty() ? 42 : std::stoi(*a.tokens.rbegin());
}
```

This however has gotten tedious to write in as many places as I'm trying to get the final token and parse it, so I've written the following to assist.

```cpp
struct A {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    const string& GetLast(const string& defaul = "") {
        return tokens.empty() ? defaul : *tokens.rbegin();
    }
    int GetLast(int defaul) {
        return tokens.empty() ? defaul : std::stoi(*tokens.rbegin());
    }
    float GetLast(float defaul) {
        return tokens.empty() ? defaul : std::stof(*tokens.rbegin());
    }
};

void Test(const A& a) {
    int i = a.GetLast(42);
}
```

This works fine but it just seems to be asking to be made into a template and allow conversion to any sort of type, provided a converter function is provided. I can't seem to find a generic solution that works, however. The following is the closest thing I can think of that should work, but I constantly get compiler errors that the template types can't be deduced.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Converter, typename... Args>
T GetLastAs(T defaul, Args ...args)
{
    return tokens.empty() ? defaul : Converter(*tokens.rbegin(), args...);
}
```

with usage `a.GetLastAs<float, std::stof>(42.0f)`

Is there a generic solution to this problem, or is that just wishful thinking on my part?

**Edit:**
I've also gotten close with the following implementation:

```cpp
template<class Converter, typename T, typename ...Args>
T GetLast(T defaul, Args ...args, Converter f = Converter()) const
{
    return tokens.empty() ? defaul : f(*tokens.rbegin(), args...);
}
```

with a converter structure defined as `struct ToInt { int operator()(const std::string& str) { return std::stoi(str); } };`
and a usage of `a.GetLast<ToInt>(42);` or `a.GetLast(42, ToInt());`
But I cannot replace the `ToInt` in the usage to `std::stoi` and I believe the reason may be because `stoi` has an overload to take `wstring` instead of `string` and the `GetLast` method cannot figure out which overload to use. I don't know if it's even possible to specify which overload to use.

Comment: Why is the function template variadic? What is `Converter` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the string into an `std::istringstream` and extract the value into a variable using the `>>` operator.

As in

```
T value{};
std::istringstream{ string_to_convert } >> value;
```

Of course, this requires `T` to be default-constructible, as well as there being an `>>` operator defined for `T`.

---

IIRC this is how [Boost lexical cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) works (or at least used to work). If you already using Boost in your project, I suggest you use its lexical cast library instead of making your own.

Or for more generic conversion (if you're using Boost) [Boost convert](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/converters_detail/stream_converter.html#boost_convert.converters_detail.stream_converter.formatting_support.numeric_base). Which can handle [different numeric bases](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/converters_detail/stream_converter.html#boost_convert.converters_detail.stream_converter.formatting_support.numeric_base).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stringstream to extract values of default constructible types like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T GetAs(const std::string& s) {
    std::stringstream ss{s};
    T t;
    ss >> t;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    std::string s{"3.5"};
    std::cout << GetAs<int>(s) << "\n";
    std::cout << GetAs<double>(s) << "\n";
    std::cout << GetAs<std::string>(s) << "\n";    
}
```

I put the default and the fact that the string is element of a vector aside, because that isnt essential for the solution.

Comment: Would using stringstreams allow me to convert to arbitrary types (provided I have a converter function), like if I wanted to convert a string of `1,2,3` to an `array<float, 3>` or `glm::vec3`? I'm assuming I'd need to write my own >> operator overload.

Comment: As a separate question, `stof` and `stoi` provides additional parameters for specifying the base of the number represented in the string. How would I specify extra parameters when it gets converted to a float or an int? This is why I originally had a variadic template in my example.

Comment: @Chris I dont quite understand what you mean with "converter function". Yes there must be a `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,T&)` to make  `ss >> t;` work. I would not recommend to overload `operator>>` for `std::array<float,3>` (at least not directly) though. I didnt consider this because the question only mentions conversions of the `stoX` family

Comment: @Chris btw the confusing thing about the `Converter` in your question is that you say it is a function but in your code it is a type. `Converter(*tokens.rbegin(), args...)` is a constructor call (and `Converter` would need to be convertible to `T` to make your code work)

Comment: @Chris hm... depends on what you actually want. If you merely want to convert to `float` and `int` then there is no reason to make it a template. For a (small) limited set of types, overloads are usually the easier alternative. What conversions do you want to enable?

Comment: I was basing the converter function off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156899) answer where a function is passed as a template argument. I thought if I can generically pass a function to the template then it wouldn't matter whether it was a stoX function or my own struct converter class.

Comment: @Chris you can pass `stoi` as non-type template parameters (like in the answer you link), though in your code `Converter` is a type