# Is passing of a function pointer through a class type in non-type template parameter allowed in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

Recently, after playing around with the C++20 feature of being able to pass [class types in non-type template parameters (**P0732R2**)](https://wg21.link/P0732R2), I've encountered something rather strange.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct abc {
    T p;
    consteval abc(T p) : p(p) { }
    consteval operator decltype(p)() const {
        return p;
    }
};

template <abc obj>
consteval auto do_something1() {
    return obj();
}

template <auto obj>
consteval auto do_something2() {
    return obj();
}

constexpr auto fun() {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(do_something1<&fun>()); // OK in Clang, fails in GCC
    static_assert(do_something2<&fun>()); // OK in both GCC and Clang
}
```

This appears to [work as intended with clang however GCC fails to compile this and gives an error saying that `fun` is not a valid template argument](https://godbolt.org/z/9hTn7jPf4).

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111957/8423261) says that function pointers should be valid template arguments as per the C++ standard.

Which compiler is correct here?

Also, weirdly enough, the same code [appears to work on both compilers when modified to work with member functions for some reason](https://godbolt.org/z/Kxnxr58sd).

> ***Note***: Something that might be useful to note is that according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page, GCC's support for **P0732R2** is complete while Clang's is still in a partial/experimental stage. So, does this mean that GCC is correct and passing of function pointers through class types in non-type template parameters shouldn't be possible, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which compiler is correct here?

Clang is correct, the code as written is valid.

GCC not handling that specific case is a known [issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97700).