# Passing function to templated class as an parameter

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project with the following structure:

```
struct WaveTable 
{
    // some code here
};

struct Table
{
    static WaveTable sinewave;
    
    // some code here
    
    static void fft(int n, float *real, float *img)
    {
        // code here
    }
};
```

Later, the structure is used like this:

```
WaveTable Table::sinewave;
```

Right now, the FFT function is hardcoded inside the structure. I want to convert these structures to templated classes, the ideia is to be able to pass the FFT implementation as a template parameter.

I've tried adding `template<typename F>` to the `Table` class, create from the struct, but it does not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as a template parameter. There are a lot of good examples here: [Function passed as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)

However, I think that in your case, passing a simple function pointer would also be good enough. You can then define multiple implementations and swap them at any time (not using templates also makes polymorphism easier because all implementations will be of the same type).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int fft1(int n, float *real, float *img)
{
    return 1;
}


int fft2(int n, float *real, float *img)
{
    return 2;
}


using FFT = std::function<int(int,float*,float*)>;

struct MyClass{
  FFT  fft;
};



int main()
{
    float a=0.f;
    float b=0.f;
    MyClass class1{fft1};
    MyClass class2{fft2};

    auto ret1 = class1.fft(0,&a,&b);
    auto ret2 = class2.fft(0,&a,&b);
    
    std::cout<<ret1<<" "<<ret2 << " ";

    return 0;
}
```